# Adding special offers to website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, e-commerce

I am new to web development. Currently I am designing a website where people can purchase different stuff. The website has got a number of special offers such as if you shop for more than $200, you get 20% off, if you shop for 3 similar items, you get a fourth one free.

Can anybody just point me in the right direction what is the best way to do this? Also if the offer changes, I donot have to change a lot of code.

thanks!

Comment: Your shop is based on Ruby on Rails? Are you using Spree?

Comment: If you want as little coding as possible, I'd recommend a hosted shop system for setting up an online shop: Great ones are e.g. [**Shopify**](http://www.shopify.com/) or [**BigCommerce**](http://www.bigcommerce.com/). They'll all have some kind of functionality you are looking for.

Comment: You could have an Offer model and a Domain Specific Language which executes the code of the Offer model for example. The Offer's part of code would "compute" the reduction.

Comment: @MrYoshiji : so the idea would be to have an offer model and when some thing comes for check out, check it against all the offers to see it any is applicable?

Comment: Is it supposed to work with "Coupon Codes"? If yes, then its very easy to trigger the active ones based on a certain amount / date in the checkout ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use various e-commerce and payment gems like the ones in [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=23).

Some more gems for this purpose are here -  [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/e_commerce) and [here too](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=payment).

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the Saas products like [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) but that's not free.

Answer (score 0):

I'll point you to some code that should help you out.

For example, " if you shop for 3 similar items, you get a fourth one free. " in ror_ecommerce this is a "Deal".  The code is here:

https://github.com/drhenner/ror_ecommerce/blob/master/app/models/deal.rb

This code is not straight forward but basically looks for the best deal an order qualifies for.

if you have buy 2 get one free you might want to implement buy 4 get 2 free and buy 6 get 3 free...

---

Similiarly ror-e has sales.  The only thing you would need to add is a condition for order.total and pass that value into the Sale.for method.

I hope this helpss

DISCLAIMER:  I wrote the code!